# SQL Server not sending email when job fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job, sql-job

I have a job with a step that runs the following code:

`SELECT * FROM TABLETHATDOESNTEXIST`

I have a SQL Server Agent Operator tied to my target email. I've set up the job so that when the job fails, it should email the Operator. However, when I run the job (and watch it fail), the email isn't sent.

I made sure to send a test email via `exec sp_send_dbmail` and also via Object Explorer > Database Mail > Send Test E-Mail and that works fine. What else am I missing here?

The job only has 1 step ("FRED" is a table that doesn't exist):
[image]

These settings were the defaults I believe:
[image]

The notifications tab of the job (the Operator here I selected is the same one everyone because there is currently only 1 Operator in the whole system):
[image]

The Operator is pretty simple to set up:
[image]

The Operator history shows that an email attempt was made, but I never received anything:
[image]

Comment: How does it fail? I think that might be important here

Comment: @DougCoats if I go to Operators > Properties > History, it says that there was a recent notification attempt, but I never received an email.

Comment: @topsail I went to the SQL job and hit Properties > Notifications and in here I selected email as the action to perform when the job completes. I then selected my Operator from the drop down (there is only 1 Operator right now in my system) and on the last drop down I selected "When the job fails".

Comment: Emails sent via Agent to an operator on failure are sent via db mail; can you see the email in `msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems`? If so, does it *also* appear in `dbo.sysmail_faileditems`?

Comment: And did you test `sp_send_dbmail` even _without_ involving SQL Server Agent and operators? e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27106243/61305 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail-sending-test-email

Comment: Also might as well add the "usual" warning that SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support back in **2019**; you should urgently be implementing your upgrade path (which you most certainly should have completed outlining by now).

Comment: @Larnu yup haha I'm in the process of upgrading my system don't worry

Comment: That's good to hear, @whatwhatwhat , and a pleasant change from "I didn't know it was unsupported!"‍♂️

Comment: @Larnu I don't see the email in sysmail_mailitems or in sysmail_faileditems. I only see the test email that I successfully received in sysmail_mailitems.

Comment: This sounds like things aren't set up correctly then. We, however, can't see what you've set up, so you'll need to provide more information here.

Comment: @Larnu ok I added more screenshots

Comment: What about the notification page of the job, @whatwhatwhat ?

Comment: @Larnu ah right, forgot that. Added!

Comment: As I remember in SQL Server 2008, after having set database_mail and/or Agent SQL server profile to send email, you should restart the SQL Server to use it...

Comment: @SQLpro good note, but I can already send emails using `sp_send_dbmail` and also by going to Database Mail > Send Test E-Mail. It's just automatically sending an email when a job fails that's the problem here

Answer (score 0):

Besides configuring:

- Management > Database Mail
- SQL Server Agent > Operators
- And adding a Notification in Job Properties to send an E-mail to
  the operator when a Job fails

You also need to configure SQL Server Agent through Properties > Alert System > Mail session

Then it should work, at least it does for me on SQL Server 2016.

[image]